# Angular Routes Issue/ routes not considering my token conditioning

Tags: angular, typescript, auth-guard

I have a an App which have 3 components
1: sellerlogin
2: Sellerhome
3: Home

after login i am redirecting the user to Sellerhome, during login i am storing a token in local storage and  checking if the token doesnt exit user should always redirected to login **but the issue is even if the token is present in the localstorage i am being able to access the login page**
**can any tell what i am doing wrong?**

my login component has a login

```
login() {
    const foremail = (this.email = this.loginForm.get('email')?.value);
    const formpassword = (this.password =
      this.loginForm.get('password')?.value);
    this.sellerservice.sellerlogin(foremail, formpassword).subscribe((res) => {
      if (res[0].email == foremail && res[0].password == formpassword) {
        localStorage.setItem('token', res[0].email);
        this.router.navigate(['/sellerhome']);
        
      } else {
        alert('Invalid credentials');
      }
    });
  }
```

and my Authentication Guard has this code

```
const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

  const router = inject(Router);
  console.log(token);
  if (!token) {
    console.log('false');
    router.navigate(['/sellerlogin']);
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
```

this is my routes

```
  {path:'sellerhome',component:SellerhomeComponent,pathMatch:'full',canActivate:[authguardsGuard]},
  {path:'sellerlogin',component:SellerloginComponent,pathMatch:'full'}
```

this is my login function in service i know i am using get instead of post but its just for time being.

```
sellerlogin(email:string,password:string):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}?email=${email}&password=${password}`);

  }
```

after login i am redirecting the user to Sellerhome, during login i am storing a token in local storage and  checking if the token doesnt exit user should always redirected to login **but the issue is even if the token is present in the localstorage i am being able to access the login page**
**can any tell what i am doing wrong?**

Answer (score 1):

From What i understood, your problem is you can directly access the login route directly even if your token is set in the localstorage.

if that's the case it is probably because you are only setting the route guard to `path:'sellerhome'` and not to `path:'sellerlogin'`, and the token checking is added to sellerlogin route.

so in order to make this work you may have to add a route guard to `sellerlogin` too (where it should pass and redirect back to logged in state).

Comment: You typically don't apply the AuthGuard to the login route itself. The AuthGuard is meant to protect routes that should only be accessible to authenticated users. The login route, on the other hand, is the entry point for users to log in and should be accessible to anyone, including those who are not yet authenticated

Comment: yes and correct me if i'm wrong, here what happens is when you are authenticated in one tab and access the login url in other one you can access th e login form, which is wrong. so either you should write a rediredtion logic in login component  or write a route guard to check whether you have valid user and if do redirect to application. and you are right usually the route guard is only applicable to the common route list but we can write as you like since its all based on the context.